# Studying for my final: Asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I am currently studying for my final in algorithms. This is not a homework problem and comes from an old final exam.

```
Show that f(n) = 4logn + log log n is big theta of logn.
```

It is obvious that log log n is considerably smaller than log n and thus insignificant. But how can I show it formally? I'm familiar with limits and L'hopital so I would appreciate it if you can show me how to do it with that method.

Comment: I don't think de l'hopital helps, since `(log n)' = 0`.

Comment: @duedl0r: unless I'm missing something, `(log n)' = 1/n`.

Comment: @blubb I suppose a limit `n -> +inf` is implied, considering @duedl0r was talking about l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Carsten: In that case I **was missing something**, and my statement is trivially correct ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember the definition of big theta. A function `f(x)` is in `Theta(g(x))` if
[image: requirement for big theta]

You have `f(x) = 4*log(x) + log(log(x))` and `g(x) = log(x)`. Now we have to show that there are values for `c_0`, `c_1` and `x_0` that satisfy the condition.

If we take `c_0 = 1` and `x_0` large enough that `log(log(x_0)) > 0` (the exact number depends on the base of your logarithm, but there is always such a number, and we don't really need to know it), then it's quite easy to show that the first inequality is true for all `x > x_0`: `log(x) <= 4*log(x) + log(log(x))` (hint: `log(log(x))` is already `> 0` and the logarithm function is monotonically increasing.

Now let's choose `c_1 = 5`. The second inequality now becomes `4*log(x) + log(log(x)) <= 5*log(x)`, which simplifies to

```
log(log(x)) <= log(x)
```

for all `x > x_0`. I'll leave that proof to you as an exercise. :-)

Comment: +1, even though using image hosting to get latex on SO is kind of cheating :P

Comment: The information you provided here is great for refreshing my memory. Thank you for the detailed solution. One more question though, when you say c_1 = 5 (or whenever you choose the constant for solving the inequalities) is it done arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes, quite arbitrarily. You just have to show that one such number exists; technically, you don't even have to know it. I chose `c_1 = 5` because you have `4log(x)` in the function and it's quite easy to prove `log(x) > log(log(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way of finding c1 , c2 and no.**

**Finding upper bound :**

```
 f(n) = 4logn+loglogn


    For all sufficience value of n>=2

        4logn <= 4 logn   
        loglogn <= logn 

    Thus , 

     f(n) = 4logn+loglogn <= 4logn+logn
                          <= 5logn
                           = O(logn)       // where c1 can be 5 and n0 =2
```

**Finding lower bound :**

```
   f(n) = 4logn+loglogn

   For all sufficience value of n>=2

      f(n) = 4logn+loglogn >= logn
    Thus,              f(n) =  Ω(logn)   // where c2 can be 1 and n0=2


  so , 
                        f(n) = Ɵ(logn)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this before? That is a very simple solution. Thank you  :)